# Why does InteractionObserver not work on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, animation

*EDIT:* This post has been edited to mark an update to a pure JS **InteractionObserver** instance from a previous jQuery contraption that made the website really slow.

The new problem is that I managed to get Rickard's idea working on a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anxlacc/pen/VwbgWBx) with some style adjustments (changed .hidden to inverse .visible class when entering) but for the life of me, it won't work on my website.

Specifically, it's the intersection I think that is not toggling, I used both a console.log and a prompt to check, and they are not launching at all, even when copying the code word by word.

**OLD CODE, FOR CONTEXT:**

```
  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $("section, img, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, span").fadeIn("slow"); });

$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $("section, img, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, span").each(function(i) {
      var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object - 200) {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: "1" }, 1000),
        $(this).find('.lefttitle').animate({left:"0px"}, 1500);
        $(this).find('.righttitle').animate({right:"0px"}, 1500);
      }}); }); });
```

**OLD CSS TITLES**

```
h2.lefttitle {float:left; text-align:left; left:10px; top:6px;}
h2.righttitle {float:right; text-align:right; right:10px; top:-6px;}
```

**OLD CSS ANIMATIONS**

```
h3, section.projdescription * {animation:fadeInUp 2s both ease;}
*.visible {animation:fadeInUp 4s both ease;}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {opacity: 0;transform: translate3d(0,10px,0);}
  100% {opacity: 1;} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work!

Here's the JS code that made the magic happen:

```
/* Margins for the Intersection */
const observerOptions = {
     root: null,
     threshold: 0,
     rootMargin: '0px 0px -100px 0px'
};

/* Add .visible Class to Intersection */
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
     entries.forEach(entry => {
         if (entry.isIntersecting) {
           entry.target.classList.add('visible');
           observer.unobserve(entry.target);
         }
     });
}, observerOptions);

/* Listener for every element on the page */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const sections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("*"));
  for (let section of sections) {
    observer.observe(section);
  }
});
```

Now here's some CSS for animations:

```
/* Set the Initial State */
section, img, h1, etc {
  transition: padding-top 1s ease, opacity 1.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;}
/* Act on Adding Visible State */
section.visible, img.visible, h1.visible, etc {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 0px;}
/* Micromanage the Transitions */
img.visible {transition-duration: 0.5s}
h1.visible {transition-duration: 0.5s;}
```

Now to keep improving on it. I'll probably change the "*" on the JS querySelector to a more concise selection (section, img, etc.) but for now, it works wonders!

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through a lot of elements every single pixel you scroll, then you animate `left` and `right` properties which forces recalculations of all objects and repaints. I would say the browser skips the animation because there are too many things going on.

1. Don't animate on scroll. Use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver).
2. Don't animate using `left`, `right`, `top`, or `bottom`. Animate using `transform: translate` (like your animation), which doesn't force recalculations of the positions of other elements. A hot fix would be to use `transform3d` to activate the 3d-rendering in the hardware.
3. You don't need to use keyframes to animate. Just use [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions), and add a relevant class to the element, that changes it's position or opacity, when the intersectionObserver triggers.

Answer (score 1):

IntersectionObserver can be tricky to understand at first. You place an observer on every single (`section`) element that you want to trigger the observer (`see 1`). Think of them as being added to an array (`entries`). The observer then triggers and gives you the array as an argument, and you need to loop through every single one of them to see if they are intersecting (`see 2`).

Sorry for not writing this in JQuery, but I'm rusty at it, because JQuery isn't really necessary today.

```js
// 2
let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  let section;

  // The same as writing ...
  // entries.forEach(function(entry) {

  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      section = entry.target;
      section.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  })
});

  // 1
document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach((section) => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
section {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

section.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

section > .text {
  transition: transform 4s;
}

section.hidden > .text {
  transform: translateX(-2rem);
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="hidden blue">
  <div class="text">Something</div>
</section>

<section class="hidden red">
  <div class="text">Something, something</div>
</section>

<section class="hidden black">
  <div class="text">Last one, now!</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Managed to get this working on a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anxlacc/pen/VwbgWBx) with some style adjustments (changed .hidden to inverse .visible class when entering) but for the life of me, it won't work on my website. Specifically, it's the intersection I think that is not toggling, I used both a console.log and a prompt to check.